# Making indirect function linking to another worksheet in excel dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using this formula to link a cell to another worksheet:

=INDIRECT("'" & $B$3 & "'!" & "B7")

Where B3 contains the name of the sheet I'm linking to and B7 is the cell in that sheet I want to pull data from

My problem is that because B7 is locked by quotation marks, I can't copy the formula across. For example, when I drag the formula down one I would like it to become B8 but it stays B7

Unfortunately removing the quotation marks makes excel think I'm using B7 from the current worksheet (hence giving an error)

Is there a work around to this / a better function to use?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is using the `CELL` function:
`=INDIRECT("'" & $B$3 & "'!" & CELL("address",B7))`

Answer (score 0):

For copying down use the ROW() function. This returns the row the formula is in - so if your formula is entered in cell G22 (say) then ROW()-15 would return 7, but when copied down to G23 would return 8. Then we add it to your formula thus

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $B$3 & "'!" & "B" & Row()-15)
```